# Create graph legend inside loop in Stata

Tags: loops, graph, stata, legend

I would like to generate graphs for different datasets, with the same variables, but in which the years change. So far I can generate the graphs, without a legend, doing this:

```
levelsof year, local(lyear)
foreach l of local lyear {
    local fig `fig' scatter mpg time if year==`l', connect(l) ||    
}
graph twoway `fig'
```

I want to add a legend showing each year. For example, doing it without a loop, I would add the option:

```
graph twoway `fig',  legend(lab(1 "2010") lab(2 "2011") lab(3 "2012"))
```

Is there a way to have the years appear in the legend as part of a loop? The years, and the number of years, change from dataset to dataset and this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My short answer is that I would not draw such a graph with a loop at all.

Here is one way to do it:

```
separate mpg, by(year) veryshortlabel 
twoway connected `r(varlist)' time, sort
```

Here is another way to do it:

```
ssc inst sepscatter 
sepscatter mpg time, sep(year) recast(connected) sort
```

You need only install `sepscatter` once.

Detail: this

```
legend(lab(1 "2010") lab(2 "2011") lab(3 "2012"))
```

is easier as

```
legend(order(1 "2010" 2 "2011" 3 "2012"))
```

Comment: The first method worked perfectly, thank you. I tried adding a marker label (mlabel) based on a variable after the "sort" option, but it only labels the first of the years in the graph and not the others. Is there a way to have it label all the years using that first method that you know of? Thanks again!

Comment: Your error report is not reproducible. Please ask a new question with full code and a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a comment on the (presumably better) answer above, but for future reference you can do all sorts of marvellous things with local macros. Just build a loop that updates the year (or anything else), then put this in a macro and use the macro for the options.

Here's a snippet from an [example](https://gist.github.com/docsteveharris/b1873ccbea7cb2c349b0) that I used to generate rug plots in Stata.

```
    foreach llevel of local llevels {
        local pposition: list posof "`llevel'" in llevels
        local rposition = `ssize'-`pposition'+1
        local iintensity=1-(0.7*((`rposition')/`maxlevels'))
        local rrug "`rrug' (scatter rugzero `rugvar'" 
        local rrug "`rrug' if `rugvar'_pickone &"
        local rrug "`rrug' `rugvar'_cat==`llevel' & `my_touse',"
        local rrug "`rrug' xaxis(`axis') msymbol(none) mlab(ruglabel)"
        local rrug "`rrug' mlabcolor(*`iintensity')"
        local rrug "`rrug' mlabposition(`clock') )"

    }
```